# In C# how can I set a string variable without escaping special characters

Tags: c#, string

I'm getting a bit tired of having to escape special characters in my strings.  So was wondering if there's an easy shorthand way for C# to take the string as is.

I know there is the @  option but with this I still need to escape "  characters which is annoying.

Ideally I would like something like

```
string myString = {The quick brown fox said "Hello"}
```

In PHP you can do this

```
$str = <<<EOD
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc syntax.
EOD;
```

Comment: Short answer is "No".

Comment: If there's no escapement how do put `"` symbol into a string?

Comment: In your example, how would you put the '}' character into your string?

Comment: c# does not have that form of a string literal.

Comment: If you're having to do this a lot, that suggests you've got a lot of literals in your code. Consider putting them into files and loading them at execution time instead. If you could give us more context, it would help.

Comment: Indeed. See Properties > Resources > Strings for example.

Answer (score 7):

Just replace the string characters like this

`simpleString = simpleString.Replace('&', '*')`;
 - where & the character you want to replace and * the character you want to get the place of the first char

Answer (score -3):

Try adding an \ before " if you need " chars in your string.

Comment: he's asking about a way to omit escaping.